# Trying to query all posts in category 4

Tags: posts, query-posts, templates

I have the following template page. I am attempting to output all of the articles from the category 4. However I am only getting some of the posts, about 20% of them. Not sure what would be causing this. Also is there a way to use the category name in the query_posts instead of the category number?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

            <div id="content">

                <div id="inner-content" class="wrap clearfix">

                    <div id="main" class="eightcol first clearfix" role="main">

                   <?php query_posts('cat=4'); ?>


                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

                            <header class="article-header">

                                <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                  <p class="byline vcard"><?php
                    printf(__('Posted <time class="updated" datetime="%1$s" pubdate>%2$s</time> by <span class="author">%3$s</span>.', 'bonestheme'), get_the_time('Y-m-j'), get_the_time(__('F jS, Y', 'bonestheme')), bones_get_the_author_posts_link());
                  ?></p>


                            </header> <!-- end article header -->

                            <section class="entry-content">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </section> <!-- end article section -->

                            <footer class="article-footer">
                                <p class="clearfix"><?php the_tags('<span class="tags">' . __('Tags:', 'bonestheme') . '</span> ', ', ', ''); ?></p>

                            </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

                            <?php comments_template(); ?>

                        </article> <!-- end article -->

                        <?php endwhile; ?>  

                        <?php else : ?>

                            <article id="post-not-found" class="hentry clearfix">
                                <header class="article-header">
                                    <h1><?php _e("Oops, Post Not Found!", "bonestheme"); ?></h1>
                                </header>
                                <section class="entry-content">
                                    <p><?php _e("Uh Oh. Something is missing. Try double checking things.", "bonestheme"); ?></p>
                                </section>
                                <footer class="article-footer">
                                    <p><?php _e("This is the error message in the page-custom.php template.", "bonestheme"); ?></p>
                                </footer>
                            </article>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div> <!-- end #main -->

                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

                </div> <!-- end #inner-content -->

            </div> <!-- end #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue regarding only returning 20% of your posts, try the following

`<?php query_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>`

Note: By default, 10 posts are returned.  `-1` will return all posts in the resulting set.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category

--

For your question about passing through the `Category Name`, you can pass through the `category_name` as parameter, which accepts the category SLUG.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

--

As mentioned by @Bart Karp, you may want to reconsider your usage of query_posts.

See the following answer for more information on usage of **WP_Query** vs **query_posts()** vs **get_posts()** - [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/26364)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid query_posts at all costs, even the Codex itself says its *the easiest, but not preferred way to alter the default query*.

Try using [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) with category parameter instead:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff' );
```

There's also [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function.

Just forget about slow query_posts() that almost always raises many problems and you should be just fine :)